# MATLAB symsum() function

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I am having trouble getting my code to work with symsum() to work. I don't know if it is because my variables are matrices or something else. But the error I am getting is the following:

"Invalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that the arguments are symbolic
variables and the body of the function is a SYM expression. When indexing, the input must be numeric, logical, or
':'. "

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
syms k

x =4
a = zeros(4,4)
b = [1 1 1 1]'

for i = 1:1:x
    a(i,i) = symsum(b(k),k,1,4) 
end
```

Comment: You can not use symbolic variable to index a matrix. Something like `b(n)` is simply not allowed. I have real problem to understand from your code what you want to do, part of it because you are using `i` as a symbolic variable and then as your iterator. It looks like symbolic math is the wrong choice in this case because all inputs are known.

Comment: Have you tried any of the examples in the documentation for `symsum`? From your example, I see no reason for you to be using symbolic math. Just use `sum(b)`.